# Viewport rendered camera differs from rendered camera, which is like fish-eye

Tags: rendering, camera, image, tracking

I have scene motion tracked. Can't understand why rendered image (like fish-eye lens) differs so much from rendered picture in viewport mode?

[image: Picture]

[image: Picture2]

[image: Picture3]

Comment: Have you set something in the Compositor?

Comment: If you are using lens distort in the compositor it could be the reason for the Error.
If not, id recommend you to use a lens distort node to temporarily fix the problem by using it as a counter part.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, there was: https://blenderartists.org/uploads/default/original/4X/b/5/1/b513687b26d74e21f757b6ee655592a3bf563920.jpeg